# wpf trigger is not binding a value

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="666" Title="Start"   Width="130"  >
    <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding DataContext.sug_strt_dte,StringFormat=\{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt\}}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding y}" Value="0" >
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="-"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
</xcdg:Column>
```

Hey its my brief code to bing date in to textblock,can anyone help me to solve

Comment: please tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: `Binding DataContext.sug_strt_dte` Looks very suspicious, but you do not provide enough information on your problem and solution attempts, so there is no way to solve your problem.

Comment: Binding DataContext.sug_strt_dte, unless you are not looking at ancestor or element name there is no need for DataContext. , you can just do Binding sug_strt_dte , but this tip will not solve it. Is this (sug_strt_dte) a property, does it implement INPC ?

Comment: If in FieldName={Binding sug_strt_dte,StringFormat=\{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt\}} it works fine.But if i use triggers it results nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong but this:

*Value="{Binding DataContext.sug_strt_dte,StringFormat={0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt}}"*

Should look like this:

*Value="{Binding DataContext.sug_strt_dte, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt}}"*

Edit:
did you check if 'y' value is not 0 after it is shown?